# Determining number of Firebase reads for nested sub-collection

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a mobile solution (iOS) that is using Firebase to aid in syncing of data between a users devices. What I have works and allows me to keep clients in sync as I wanted to. However from testing, my reads are a bit out of control for larger data sets and I need to do some optimization. To that end, I wanted to make sure that my understanding of how reads are counted was correct (I am still a newbie at Firebase).

My data is structured like this:

[image]

Its a bit nested I agree, but for all the uses cases it seems to be the best way to do things to minimize redundancy, e.g. there are relationship between Cats and Dogs and Birds, but I only store one copy of each, not multiple. In addition, each users data is segregated from the other users and I need the ability to version the data. Put that all together and with the requirement to alternate collections and documents, you get what you see.

Based on this structure, I can create queries like this:

```
Firestore.firestore().collection("userid1").document("data").collection("version0").document("Cats").collection("data").whereField("modifiedDate" isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: someDoubleValue).getDocuments(completionCallback)
```

This gets me the data I need and seems to only return the number of items I think it should. However, am I correct in saying that if there are 100 Cat type documents (Cat1...Cat100), but only 3 of them have a modifiedDate that is greater than my query parameter, when the data is returned to me, I will only be "charged" for 3 reads? Or have I don't something completely silly here and I am getting charged for all 100 even though I only get 3 documents back in the callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The billing doesn't work any different for subcollections than it does for top-level collections.  You are only billed for the documents transferred, not the entire set of documents in the collection (unless you do request every document).

Cloud Firestore scales massively, and it's expected that you might have a massive number of documents in a collection.  Billing a read for each and every document in a collection for each query against that collection would be insanely expensive.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for sanity checking me. I thought that had to be the case but since I am seeing orders of magnitude larger numbers of reads that I expected, I felt I had to double check.